# Update page with Jquery using entity from doctrine2

Tags: jquery, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

Suppose you render on a template "select" all the names of the clients of your table clients.

Now you create a script that looks for that select change event.

What I need is that some info  of the currently selected user would be printed on the page, lets say email field.

But how do I get the client object within the script to ask for that field?

I have read something about encoding all my users on json, may it be? If so... would you mind setting an example of this?

this is my template

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script >
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#select_clients').change(function(){
            $("#email").text(?????);
          });
        });
    </script>
{%  endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h3>Clients</h3>
    <select id="select_users">
        {% for client in clients %}
        <option value = {{client.id}}>{{client.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <p id = "email"></p>
{% endblock %}
```

of course it assumes I am sensing all the clients from the controller:

```
 public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $clients= $em->getRepository('TESTBundle:Client')->findAll();

    return $this->render('TESTBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        'clients' => $clients,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as OP explained, this needs to be done at server also.

so we first gets the email:

```
$dql = "SELECT c, e FROM Clients c JOIN c.email e ORDER BY c.created DESC";
$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql);
$clients = $query->getResult();
```

now render this in twig:

```
<option data-client-email="{{client.email|escape}}" value="{{client.id}}">{{client.name}}</option>
```

if you want to see `textContent` of the selected option use another jQuery call.

```
$('#slist').change(function(e){
    console.log( 'id of client is: '+ $(this).val() + '<br>' );

    nameOfClient = $('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').text();
    console.log( 'name of client is: '+ nameOfClient + '<br><br>' );

    emailOfClient = $('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').data().clientEmail;
    console.log( 'email of client is: '+ emailOfClient + '<br><br>' );
});
```

Please take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/ghr7L5j5/2/

This is also can be done with JSON response from server in separate request to avoid all those calls to the DOM.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to access the method 
->getEmail() of the currently selected client. 
If it was on the template I could use {{client.email}}, but at the front end I dont have the client entity to ask. thats my problem :(

Comment: please take a look: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#list-of-bugs

Comment: ohh man I see, I can put the info I will use later on the front end right in the html of the page isn´t it?
That could solve this problem so the answer is corret now!
But please if is not a problem, explain me a little bit  how to implement the json thing. It would be very useful later!